# I am receiving an error when running a time_decompose function from the anomalize library in R

Tags: r, types, arguments, tibbletime

After installing R base and R studio, and running the standard example from: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anomalize/versions/0.1.1/topics/time_decompose.

I get the error:

> `Error in !.key : invalid argument type`

I tried using the `as_tibble` and `as_tbl_time` functions to prepare data to no avail, getting the same error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(anomalize)
library(dplyr)

data(tidyverse_cran_downloads)

# Basic Usage
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  time_decompose(count, method = "stl")
```

I expected to see a time decomposed object but get the error message, noted above.

Comment: Just making sure, you installed `R` base and `RStdio` and the required libraries,  `dplyr` and `anomalize`?  I can't reproduce the error and  probably the libraries didn't load properly?

Comment: So it's not that the libraries didn't load, it executes the library imports done but when it executes the time decompose function, it returns the error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're hitting a compatibility mismatch between tidyverse and anomalize.

Find a workaround (downgrade) and details here:
https://github.com/business-science/anomalize/issues/40